# Cant find a solution on how to place same conf files in different products

Tags: java, eclipse, product, workspace, tycho

I have a specific problem with my workspace in eclipse.

The project is an OSGi project with JavaFx UI. There are bundles and I made 3 features from these bundles. I have 2 products from these features. One feature is core and two other have diffefent implementations of some bundles. Then my products have two features each. As you guess product-1 has core and impl-1 features and product-2 has core and impl-2 features.

Ok but not yet, some more explanations so I can ask my question :)
These features with different implementations have different working directories since they need different native libraries to run.

Here is the basic project setup:

```
project
|
+---core
|   |   
|   +---plugin.api
|   +---plugin.impl.1
|   +---plugin.impl.2
|                   
+---external
|   |   
|   +---working_dir_1 (only for product 1)
|   |   |   aaaa1.dll
|   |   |   aaaa2.so
|   |
|   +---working_dir_2 (only for product 2)
|   |   |   bbbb1.dll
|   |   |   bbbb2.dll
|   |   |   bbbb3.so
|   |   |   bbbb4.so
|   |   
|   +---config  (shared)
|   |   +---Database
|   |   +---Log
|   |   +---Theme
|   |   +---conf1
|   |   +---conf2
|   |   +---conf3
|   |   \---conf4
|                   
+---features
|   +---core.feature
|   +---core.1.feature
|   \---core.2.feature
|               
+---products
|   +---product.1
|   +---product.2
|                   
+---releng
|   +---project.configuration
|   \---project.target
|
+---tests
```

As you can see above application can use conf files by reaching parent folder. In java it is just like this:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + ".." + File.separator + CONFIGURATION_FOLDER_NAME;
```

This is ok. I and everyone on my team can run a product of choice with just one click. I loved the project setup.

Oh I added tycho tag and never mentioned about it. We also use tycho to auto build our project. With it we can have 4 products. Win and Linux runnables for each product-1 and product-2. When building and materialising products tycho copy needed native librarires and configuration files. But when configuration files copied tycho places them on the working directory of the created product. So application cant find the conf files since it looks up conf files in the parent folder of the materialised product.

This is my problem rigth now. When ever I want to build with tycho I have to change the code above to this:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + CONFIGURATION_FOLDER_NAME;
```

How can I solve this?
We are developping on windows 10 and using eclipse and tycho as mentioned before.

I dont want to multiply configurations since it will be a hussle to change two files each time.

I tried symbolic link to place conf folder links in working dirs. It actually worked but when everyone pulled, links didnt work. I guess symbolic links on windows dont work in different computers.

I can change project structure as long as it solves the problem.

Note:
Configurations include application level configs that can be changed by non-developper staff (like just openning a file and changing a property from true to false). This is why we didnt put them in bundle. If this was not the case, all bundles will have their related configs in respective bundle resource or in a fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put configuration into a bundle, and add `Bundle-Shape: dir` and then you could read the config files through the bundles classloader independent of the real location.

Comment: Configurations include application level configs that can be changed by non-developper staff. This is why we didnt put them in a bundle. If this was not the case all bundles should have their related configs in respective bundle resource or in a fragment. This is a request from client :( But it is in my mind for a solution at least. Thanks

Comment: But does it really matter where the configuration is located? Because as with 'Bundle-Shape: dir' you will end up with a plain directory that contains the files